# Parse multiline fixed-width text files in ruby

Tags: ruby, fixed-width

I am trying to parse a multi-line fixed-width file in ruby and it seems I can't parse the information I need. I can parse fine when the information is in 1 line. for example:

```
Name      LastName         DOB
John      Doe              01/01/2001
Jane      Doe              01/02/2002
```

but where I am facing a challenge is when the file does have a structure like below

```
This message needs to be                 AccountId: 7854639
parsed in a single key                   Phone: 823972839563
of the json that I want to produce       Email: test@test.com
```

The multiline text is always let's say on the same coordinates, and it is dynamic. Not sure how to parse this and map into a json value for example.

Comment: It's hard to say w/o knowing what "dynamic" means, but it *looks* like you have some free-form text following by a colon-delimited key/value pair. This means you could read *n*-lines of text, grab everything before the `SomeWord: value<EOL>` and the `SomeWord`/value pair, join the trimmed free-form text with spaces, and put all the key/value pairs and the free-form text into a hash.

Comment: Dynamic means the content. I know that the text will always be 4 lines for example and each line can't be more than 100 characters. The values on the right might also not exists, for example i can have account and phone but email might be missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simplistic, un-golfed approach:

```rb
freeform_text = str.split('\n').map do |s|
  m = s.match(/^(.*)\s+(.*):(.*)$/)
  m[1] ? m[1].strip : ''
end.join(' ')

# Produces:
# "This message needs to be parsed in a single key of the json that I want to produce"
```

There are other, more-idiomatic approaches, but this gives you a hint of the direction to take.

Answer (score 1):

```rb
str = "This message needs to be          AccountId: 7854639
parsed in a single key                   Phone: 823972839563
of the json that I want to produce       Email: test@test.com"

p str.scan(/([^\s]+:[^\n]+)/).flatten
```

See [Ruby demo](https://ideone.com/0eWvsW).

Comment: Going to give this a try. Not sure how this works if the text expands more than 3 lines, like 6 for example. I need the text not the email, phone and account